# bootstrap clearfix make panel header blow out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a standard panel header with some left and right aligned elements.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">


    <div class="panel-heading clearfix" >
        <h4 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">{{ album.name }}<span class="badge">{{ album.image_count }}</span></h4>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-target="#mymodal" type="button" data-toggle="modal">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="">
                <span id="selected" style="display: none">here</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="panel-body">
        body content
    </div>
</div>
```

if I apply the clearfix class to the panel the height of the panel heading blows out to some 450 px. If I leave the clearfix off I get the below.
I tried putting the same code on bootply and I don't see the problem there. I have been looking through the css in chrome but can't find the problem...

[image: without clearfix]

This is the css that I have added to the page:

```
.col-lg-2 .col-md-3 .col-sm-4 .col-xs-6 {
    background-color: #840c15;
}

.thumbnail {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
}

.img-responsive {
    background-color: goldenrod;
}

.no-gutter [class*="-2"] {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}

.photo-group .photo-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.photo-group .photo-wrapper .photo {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}

.photo-group .photo-wrapper .photo-label {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    float: right;
    color: #ebab11;
}

.photo-tick {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    float: right;
}

.unticked {
    color: #6b606c;
}

.ticked {
    color: #55eb2d;
}


#side-panel {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;


    text-align: center;
}

#center-panel {
    margin-left: 280px;

    text-align: center;
}
#center-panel .row-fluid {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: can you post any relevant css?

Comment: added css @BradleyWilson

Comment: try adding margin-top:0; to the photogroup class .photogroup {margin-top:0;} also put z-index:1; on the header container

Comment: It was the last 3 css classes that screwed it up. I had stolen that code from somewhere and it wasn't exactly done the bootstrap way. I've reimplemented the sidebar and solved the problem.